# FadeIn/Out step-by-step depending on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, fade

I have this HTML/CSS http://jsfiddle.net/thekillerdev/sB49B/2/

And what i would like to do is something almost like a parallax scroll (i think).
Depending on where the person is scrolling the .items would fadeout and fadein the next one.

something like..

- If the person scrolled (scrollTop) 200px down, the .item02 would be on opacity:1, and the rest on opacity:0.
- If the person scrolled (scrollTop) 300px down, the .item02 would be on opacity:0.5, the .item03 on opacity:0.5 and the rest on opacity:0.

How could i achieve this kind of animation? any heads up on this?

```
Edit:
jQuery, JS, anykind of language that works in a browser is accepted =]
```

Any more info needed, i'm around to provide it.

Thank you for the time

Comment: I don't think this is possible with only CSS. It will be with jQuery though! My knowledge of jQuery is not sufficient enough to help you, but I'm pretty sure someone's is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/sB49B/18/

Comment: Awesome @michael, this is it... i just have one little tweak, how would i do to fadeout in the same proportion the other itens? i mean, the item before the one showing up, goes from 1 to 0 opacity?